# Spread types may only be created from object types angular error angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I am beginner in angular, I am trying to implement CRUD application using Firestore referring some youtube videos.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OrdersService } from '../../shared/services/orders/orders.service';
import { Orders } from 'src/app/shared/models/orders/orders.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-orders',
  templateUrl: './admin-orders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-orders.component.css']
})
export class AdminOrdersComponent implements OnInit {

  list: Orders[];
  constructor(private service: OrdersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.service.getOrders().subscribe(actionArray =>{
      this.list = actionArray.map(item => {
        return {
          id: item.payload.doc.id,
          ...item.payload.doc.data()  //getting error over here
        } as Orders;
      })
    });

  }

}
```

If I run this using ng serve my application works as well as shows data as required but while **ng build** its not giving output showing above error.

Comment: Try adding a type to what data returns or cast in within your function `...(item.payload.doc.data() as {})`

Comment: What does this line returns `item.payload.doc.data()`?

Comment: Please share stackblitz example

Comment: Update TypeScript, this restriction has been lifted for most types.

Comment: item.payload.doc.data() this line return the object data from database which is then fade up to an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to this:

```js
this.service.getOrders().subscribe(actionArray => {
    this.list = actionArray.map(item => {
        const data = item.payload.doc.data() as Orders;
        const id = item.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well I didn't find where the error was so I removed de-structuring where the error was persisting and manually retrieved all the data

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { OrdersService } from '../../shared/services/orders/orders.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-admin-orders',
      templateUrl: './admin-orders.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./admin-orders.component.css']
    })
    export class AdminOrdersComponent implements OnInit {
    
      orders:any;
      constructor(private service: OrdersService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
    
        this.service.getOrders().subscribe(actionArray =>{
          this.orders = actionArray.map(item => {
            return {
              id: item.payload.doc.id,
              addr: item.payload.doc.data()['addr'],
              date: item.payload.doc.data()['date'],
              email: item.payload.doc.data()['email'],
              mobile: item.payload.doc.data()['mobile'],
              name: item.payload.doc.data()['name'],
              occassion: item.payload.doc.data()['occassion'],
              plan: item.payload.doc.data()['plan'],
              price: item.payload.doc.data()['price'],
              time: item.payload.doc.data()['time'],
            };
          })
        });
    
      }
    }
```

like it is shown above ... still if someone points out where I was doing the mistake it will be helpful